# Import VBScript General Date Time Into MS Access Date/Time Column

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, import

### Setup

I have a VBScript for driving the stress testing of a web service. The script creates a data file of measurements, with each record timestamped with a general date/time:

```
FormatDateTime(Now(), 0)
```

This creates dates like

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss [AM|PM]
```

I need to import this data file into a MS-Access 2003 database. The table in the Access database has a column called `TimeStamp` with a data type of `Date/Time` and format of `General Date`.

My import spec has a field named `Timestamp` with a Date Type of `Date/Time`. In the `Dates, Times, and Numbers` frame the following options are selected:

> ```
> Date Order: MDY
> Date Delimiter: /
> Time Delimiter: :
> Four Digit Years: Checked
> ```

The data file is tab delimited with field names in the first row.

### Problem

When I import my data file, each record fails on the Timestamp field with a `Type Conversion Failure` error.

### Question

Is there a way to import the data as-is, or do I have to first "massage" the timestamp field into 24-hour date/time format? If the latter, is there a way to format the timestamp in my VBScript code to write the date/time in 24-hour format? I tried

```
FormatDateTime(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

but VBScript barfed at that.

Comment: Are you filling the date field from VBScript, or are you writing the date to a file and importing it into the DB?

Comment: The VBScript is writing writing data to a flat file (tab delimited) and timestamping each record. Since I have 450,000+ records in the file, I'd like to import into Access in order to filter, query and do analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/can-i-make-vbscript-format-dates-for-me.html); I can mimic VB's `Format()` function to format the date as 24-hour date/time:

```
Function Format(vExpression, sFormat) 

    set fmt = CreateObject("MSSTDFMT.StdDataFormat") 
    fmt.Format = sFormat 

    set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
    rs.Fields.Append "fldExpression", 12 ' adVariant 

    rs.Open 
    rs.AddNew 

    set rs("fldExpression").DataFormat = fmt 
    rs("fldExpression").Value = vExpression 

    Format = rs("fldExpression").Value 

    rs.close: Set rs = Nothing: Set fmt = Nothing 

End Function
```

From the article:

> The MSSTDFMT object depends on the
>   availability of MSSTDFMT.dll, which is
>   installed by Visual Studio 6.0.

The MSSTDFMT.dll appears to be available on Windows XP and Windows 2003 servers; I checked a few machines that have never had MS Visual Studio installed and the DLL was present.

I changed my VBScript code to use this function to put the dates in a format Access can import:

```
Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Excellent. Regardless, I still think you should import as ISO rather than under the local date format - MS is notorious for getting it wrong when there is some ambiguity.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem Access recognizes ISO dates when importing either, no matter how the column is defined.

Answer (score 1):

VBScripts FormatDateTime function does not supprot general format strings only a constrained set of constants and 0 is the only choice you have to include both date and time.

Could it be the prescence of the AM/PM that is causing confusion?

You are in a US locale?

Try `SetLocale(2057)`

This puts the script in to the en-GB (UK) locale.  The default date time format is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.  Its 24 hour perhaps your import would prefer that format.

Answer (score 1):

Why not skip the data file and write the results directly to the database?

EDIT:
Or use this script to move data from the file to the DB.

```
Set DataFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("FileName",1)

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=database.mdb"

Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRecordset.CursorLocation = 3
objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM TableName" , objConnection, 3, 3

Do Until DataFile.AtEndOfStream
    arrTemp = Split(DataFile.ReadLine, vbTab)
    If IsArray(arrTemp) Then
        objRecordset.AddNew
        objRecordset("FieldName1") = arrTemp(0)
        objRecordset("FieldName2") = arrTemp(1)
        objRecordset("FieldName3") = arrTemp(2)
        objRecordset.Update
    Else
        'Only one item of data is on this line
    End If 
Loop 

DataFile.Close
objConnection.Close
Set DataFile = Nothing
Set objRecordset = Nothing
Set objConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: That's a thought, but would require some extensive surgery to the scripts I inherited. Perhaps in the long run...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help, but is there any way for you to process your date output in your VBScript to make sure that the dates have leading zeroes and 4-digit years? If you do that, then you could import it as a text field and then process it, because you would know that the first 10 characters are the unambiguous date, and then you could parse the time with a little bit of data massaging. If that isn't possible, but you know that there's a SPACE between the date and the time, then you could again import as text and parse the date from the time using the space as your delimiter, and then process the time field.

I know you said you didn't want to have to parse the data after import, but if you can't get the import data into a format that Access can process, then you don't have a choice.

Another thought:

Have you tried Excel's import functionality? It may resemble the Access import superficially, but it often gets you completedy different results on the exact same data.

Sorry I can't offer anything definitive, though.